# Sock JS Client send message to remote application endpoint

Tags: java, angularjs, sockjs

I have an Angular JS Client that subscribes to a RabbitMQ server on another Machine. The Server resides on another machine as well. I am able to successfully subsribe and receive topic messages published by the server to the broker. The problem now arises when i want to send a message directly to the remote server's sockjs endpoint. Client Side Code

```
service.CHAT_BROKER = "/auction/trade";
var bid = {
token : "26cbf0fe0247dd9d350b39454bcb28dbf882200a",
auctionId : "auctionId"
};
service.send = function(message) {
console.log("Sending Bid" + bid);
socket.client.send(service.CHAT_BROKER, {priority: 9},
JSON.stringify(bid));
    };
```

And remote server side code :

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/auction").withSockJS();
}

@MessageMapping("/trade")
public void executeBid(Bid bid, Principal principal) {
    System.out.println("Auction Received " + bid);
    }
```

Am getting the the following error from the client :

/auction/trade' is not a valid destination.
Valid destination types are: /temp-queue, /exchange, /topic, /queue, /amq/queue, /reply-queue/.